# ~ど at the end of a sentence?

Tags: suffixes

> フェイズスキルにはいたらねど

And the next sentence

> それゆえに「螺旋撃」は武の極致

I don't know how to break up the hiragana in the first sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

フェイズスキルにはいたらねど here means フェイズスキルには至らないが ("although it does not reach (the level of) *phase skill*", "although it's not as good as *phase skills*").

ねど is a combination of ね and ど, both of which are words from archaic Japanese.

- **ね**: [已然形](http://thejapanesepage.com/w/index.php?title=Conjugation_Bases#.E5.B7.B2.E7.84.B6.E5.BD.A2_.28Izenkei.29) form of [ず](http://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%9A), which is equivalent to ～ない (="not") in modern Japanese.
- [**ど**](http://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A9): ≒ ～が/～けれども in modern Japanese. (eg 金あれど = 金はあるが)

Perhaps the best-known phrase that uses this ねど would be [武士は食わねど高楊枝](http://kotowaza-allguide.com/hu/bushiwakuwanedo.html).

Comment: I see, I thought maybe the mangaka forgot the "ke" in "kedo", because I've never seen it in this form before. And phase skill huh? RPG mangas are a different breed... thanks!